# Loading log4j.xml from outside of war file

Tags: spring, log4j

For my spring application, I have a requirement to move log4j.xml outside of war file. I have been searching for solutions, and found following ways:

1. org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener: this did not work as war is not expanded on tomcat.
2. Passing jvm property (-Dlog.Localtion=....): Since log4j file is application specific, I do not think this is good way to do this.

I am wondering what is best way to solve this. I believe Spring should make it easy someway, it's just I don't much about it.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the location of your log4j.xml in your context config file:

```
<bean id="log4jInitialization"
 class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
   <property name="targetClass"
      value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer" />
   <property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging" />
   <property name="arguments">
      <list>
         <value>/any/path/log4j.xml</value>
      </list>
   </property>
</bean>
```

Source http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/how-to-specify-log4j-configuration-in-spring-application

Answer (score 0):

You can check `org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer`. You can pass the location of log4j.xml to this class.It also takes care of resolving property place holders.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener` in your web.xml - just add this elements:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>../path/to/config</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Log4jConfigListener only works when WAR file is expanded on tomcat, so this does not work for me since WAR file is not expanded on server.